# Backup scheduled by 2 weekly once but happens on every week in Marklogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

I have scheduled the backup by 2 weekly once but it's happening every week, Here are the details:

```
backup enabled  true
backup directory    /backup/testdb
backup type weekly
backup period   2
backup days monday
backup start time   10:00 pm
max backups 2
include replicas    false
journal archiving   false
incremental backup  false
```

I have scheduled a backup period as 2 weeks once as per the Marklogic document interval.
Let me know how to achieve 2 weekly once a backup

Comment: If type is "weekly" and backup period is "2", then yes, it should backup every 2 weeks. If that's not happening, it's a bug. Do you have a support contract, or are you just trying MarkLogic out?

Comment: Thanks, I have a support contract, I will raise the ticket with Marklogic,